# Why isn't min-height working like min-width when the viewport gets reduced?

Tags: html, css

Other than defining the minimum width of the element, min-width is also used to regulate the behavior of the element when the viewport itself is reduced.

For example,

```css
.div1 {
    border: 5px solid;
    padding:25px;
    background-color: orangered;
    min-width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>
```

Now, if you start reducing the viewport, the element does not overflow, but it shrinks until it hits the min-width, at which point, it starts to overflow. But why isn't the same thing happening with min-height?

```css
.div1 {
    border: 5px solid;
    padding:25px;
    background-color: orangered;  
    min-height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div><br>
```

Now, if you start reducing the height of the browser, the height of the element is not going to start shrinking until it hits the min-height, instead it starts overflowing immediately. Why? Why is it shrinking when you reduce the width of the viewport until it hits the min-width point, but it's not shrinking when you reduce the height of the viewport? It just overflows instantly.

Comment: because the default height of a div is its content and the default width of a div it's 100% of its parent

Comment: I was thinking what is the point of having min-width, when you can just set a width and then a max-width. That way, the width is always fixed, but since max-width overrides the width, the content wouldn't exceed the max-width, but when i tested it, it turned out that neither max nor min-width override the width. So, is that a mistake on behalf of MDN to claim that the max/min-width override the width property?

Comment: max/min-width are never meant to override the width. They simply set a min and max value to the width, that's all.

Comment: I see. Thank you.